# HTML Button & Text Field

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I'm trying to make a HTML Chat but when I try to put a Submit Button next to a Text Field,
the Button Position is always a few Pixels below the Text Field Position.

```
<center>
<input name="msg" id="inputField" type="text">
<button id="submitBtn" onclick="javascript:sendChatMsg" value="Send">
     Send
</button>
</center>
```

The Stylesheet:

```
#inputField{
width:830;
height:50;
font-size:20px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#000000;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#FFFFFF;
margin-top:5px
    }
#submitBtn{
background-color:#000000;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#FFFFFF;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top:9px;
height:50px;
width:100px;
text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: The `<center>` element was deprecated  in 1954. Use CSS instead.

Comment: **1954**....doubtful ! :) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your text field

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0):

try add in inputField   [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yesHI)

```
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align:bottom;
```

**CSS**

```
#inputField{
  border: none;
  outline:none;
width:830;
height:50px;
font-size:20px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#000000;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#FFFFFF;
margin-top:5px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align:bottom;
    }
```

or change `vertical-align:bottom;` in `vertical-align:top;` end dell `margin-top: 5px;` `margin-top:9px;`

Answer (score -1):

Height and Width has number but no units:

```
width:830;
height:50;
```

Change to this:

```
width:830px;
height:50px;
```

Comment: Why is it not an answer? Input field does not have a valid height while the button does. That is why one is 50px tall and one is not.

Comment: he is saying why button going down